# Google Sign in returns to login after account selection

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-signin

Google Sign in is working on ios (published) but doesn't work in release on Android. On hitting the button the Sign in process is started and you can select an account but after selection of the right account it just return to the login.. nothing happens... However on my emulator it does work. -_-`.

I checked SHA-1 and SHA-256 (release-keys) and updated the google-service.json file.

```
  signWithGoogle() async {
    final googleSignin = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser =
    await googleSignin.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser!.authentication;
    final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    ) as GoogleAuthCredential;
    final res = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(res.user!.uid).set({
      'name' : res.user!.displayName,
      'email': res.user!.email,
      'uid': res.user!.uid,
      'image': res.user!.photoURL,
    }, SetOptions(merge : true));
    return res.user;
  }
```

I'm using google_sign_in package.

Comment: Are you trying an apk built locally or from google play directly?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have uploaded an aab bundle to Google play for internal testing. But sign in doesn’t work on a physical Android phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 sets of sha keys. When you upload an app bundle google signs an apk. This key needs to be updated in firebase.

You have to copy keys from app sign in key section. The release jks's keys is named here as upload key certificate.. use the app sign in key's sha 1 and sha256 in firebase and download the json. Add it to the app and reupload. This should work as expected

[image: preview]

Comment: Thank you! I didn’t realise Google created new ones upon release!